# What is the expected value of distinct numbers in an array of integer numbers of size n?

Tags: probability, expected-value

We have an array of size $n$ and the elements of the array can be from $1$ to $N$, in a way that the number $1 \leq i \leq N$ has probability $P_i$ to be chosen for any place in array. Define $X$ a random variable for each array that shows how many distinct numbers exist in the array.

What is the mean(expected value) of $X$?

To demonstrate an example, if $N = 5$ and $n = 7,$ an array can be $[3, 5, 5, 1, 3, 1, 5],$ thus $X = 3$ because the set of distinct numbers is $\{1, 3, 5\}$

Comment: Presumably your array has integer entries, yes?  That should be specified.  Given that, can you compute the probability that a particular value $i$ is chosen exactly once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- given a particular $i$, what is the probability it does not get selected in the first position?
- given a particular $i$, what is the probability it does not get selected in any position?
- what is the expected number of $i$s not selected in any position?
- what is the expected number of $i$s selected in at least one position?

Comment: the probability for each $i$ to be chosen in any position is $P_i$, thus the probability it does not get selected in any position is $1 - P_i$ so the expected value of any $i$ not to be selected in any position would be $i(1-P_i)^n)$ but I can't seem to solve your 4th hint and to relate the hints into a solution :(

Comment: I would have thought the answers were $1-P_i$;  $(1-P_i)^n$; $\sum_i (1-P_i)^n$; $n- \sum_i (1-P_i)^n$ with the last of these answering your question

Comment: Would you please explain about hints 3 and 4? I can get that the probability of any $i$ not to be selected in array at all is $(1-P_i)^n$ but I can't quite get why is the expected value of $i$s not to be selected in any position is equal to the sum of that. Shouldn't we multiply $i$ to every $(1-P_i)^n$ before summation?

Comment: Why do we subtract the summation from $n$? Shouldn't that be the number of distinct  numbers in total and thus N?

Comment: @MahdiGheidi that is likely a typo, having not realized that $n$ and $N$ were distinct variables.  As for the math behind this all, recall that the expected value operator is *linear*.  That is to say, $E[\alpha A + \beta B] = \alpha E[A]+\beta E[B]$ for any random variables $A,B$ and scalars $\alpha,\beta$.  So, the expected value of a sum of random variables collectively is just the sum of the expected values of the individual random variables.

Comment: @MahdiGheidi as for multiplying by $i$... no.  There is no reason to.  You may be confusing yourself with other problems where you were interested in the sum of distinct appearing numbers or something.  Here, we simply add $1$ (*not $i$*) to the overall total if the number $i$ did not appear anywhere and $0$ otherwise if it did appear.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for the clarification. considering what you said I came up with a slightly different solution. Define $X_i$ a random variable for each array where it equals 1 if number i has appeared in the array and 0 otherwise. thus $E[X] = E[X_1 + X_2+ ... + X_N] = E[X_1] + ... E[X_N]$ thus $E[X]$ = $\sum_{i=1}^N 1 * (1-(1-P_i)^n) = N - \sum_{i=1}^N (1-P_i)^n$ 
is that a correct solution to problem?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but it isn't a different solution.  It is exactly the same solution that was suggested by Henry... noting that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N(1-(1-P_i)^n) = N - \sum\limits_{i=1}^N(1-P_i)^n$

Comment: Noted. Thanks a lot